# Why isn't the 'Map Colors' fixup changing text colors?

Tags: pdf

I saw this question some where, I think Reddit, but I can't find it. I have same issue.
Please see the screenshot beneath. I've uploaded [the PDF to mega.nz](https://mega.nz/file/3pZzEKJC) I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Version 2019.010.20064.

I'm trying to convert the book's default (C, M, Y, K) = (99%, 98%, 18%, 6%) (ie dark purple) to [(90, 0, 90, 0) (green)](https://www.colorhexa.com/1aff1a). After I click 'OK' and click 'Fix', Adobe Acrobat executes the fixup, but the color fails to change. Why?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. I don't know if this is the right site to ask this question since it is quite an application-specific one. Also, I don't think it is really a Computer Graphics problem or something that fits into one of the categories defined in the [on-topic pages](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). A better place to ask this question is the [Adobe Support Community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/bd-p/acrobat?page=1&sort=latest_replies&filter=all).

Comment: You will probably get a faster and more accurate answer there.